# How to run a function at a specific time in iOS?

Tags: ios, function, time, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I want to run a function in my app at a specific time. At 5pm I'd like my app to display a  simple alertView telling the user it's 5pm.

It's safe to assume the app is active and open at that time. I'm aware how to run a function after a delay (but that is dependant on when the method is first called).

One approach is possibly sending a local notification. Is that the best approach? I was hoping to avoid using that as it depends on the user granting permissions to send notifications.

Comment: Can you assume that the user will have the app open the whole time? If the user might close the app, I think you'll have to use notifications

Comment: The user may close the app between the scheduling of the notification and re-opening the app. So yes, that's why I was considering a notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "it's safe to assume the app is active and open at that time" — though I don't see how it could possibly be safe to assume that — then a timer (NSTimer) is most appropriate. Simply use the difference between what time it is now and the time you want the function called to tell the timer when to fire.

Local notifications are to notify *the user* about something, when your app is *not* frontmost. In other words, they are a way of telling the *system* to provide some notifying interface on your behalf. Notification can appear in the notification center, on the lock screen, as a banner or alert, and as a sound. If that isn't what you want, don't use a local notification.

It's true that if your app happens to be frontmost when a local notification fires, then the local notification notifies your app rather than showing the user a banner / alert. If that's acceptable, then this *would* be a reasonable use of a local notification. But don't use a local notification as a substitute for doing your own timing arithmetic! Use it because you want to notify the user.

Comment: ... and when the timer fires, check that it is indeed 5pm, in case the phone went to sleep for a while.

Comment: @gnasher729 Time does not stop if the phone sleeps. If, as the user assumes, the app is awake and frontmost, 5 PM will be 5 PM even if the app slept in the meantime.

Comment: As I mentioned in another comment, the user may close the app between setting the timer and then re-opening the app just before 5pm. In that case an NSTimer wouldn't be suitable?

Comment: @AndrewDavis I don't see why not. As I said before, time didn't magically stop just because the app was closed. NSTimer doesn't work by counting, it works by thinking. :) You (and @gnasher) seem to be making a false assumption that NSTimer is stupid. It isn't. To see this, ask yourself how an local notification actually works under the hood so as to know when it's time to fire. Hint: it uses an NSTimer. Oh, sorry, did I give the answer out loud?